# Qt::Tool window diasappears when application become inactive

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, kde4

I have problem with keeping Qt::Tool window visible when the application becomes inactive. The application is running and there are 2 windows opened - main and additional with Qt::Tool flag set. When I open/switch to other app e.g Konosole the main window remains visible but second disappears - so if I want to e.g. rewrite some data from the tool window to a  document I need to keep switching between them.

There is no such problem with `Qt::ToolTip` but it looks different.

I've also tried `setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacAlwaysShowToolWindow,true)` but since I'm running Linux with KDE4 it doesn't help. Also `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` is not what I'm trying to get.

Is there any way to keep it visible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, but wasn't able to fix it by modifying code since it seems to be a window manager setting, which you should be able to tweak in KDE Control Center.

I don't have KDE 4 installed so I'm not sure where the setting is there, but in the KDE 3.5 Control Center, if you look under `Desktop`->`Window Behavior` and then click on the `Advanced` tab, you can un-check a box called `Hide utility windows for inactive applications` to keep your tool window visible.  Hopefully, there's a similar setting in the KDE 4 Control Center.

Comment: Well, I think that there is way to do it using two flags:

   1. `Qt::ToolTip`
   2. `Qt::WindowTitleHint`

Now the window looks like `Qt::Tool` but I'm not sure if it always behave same way.