# Can I make QT Designer not hide undocked panels when it's inactive?

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm using Qt Designer (4.8.1), on multiple monitors.   I like to undock some of Designer's widgets/panels (ie, Object Inspector, Widget Box) and put them on one screen, while I have the main design area on another.   If I switch to another program that takes up one screen (like my code editor, or QtAssistant), Designer hides its undocked panels.   Is there any way to change that?   Eg, so I can pull up Assistant over the main Designer window, but still see (Designer's) Object Inspector.

I could probably get used to it, but I'd rather fix it.   More importantly, if this is standard Qt behavior, I'll need to know how to correct/change it in my own programs (I haven't used dockWidgets yet, but I plan to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a KDE setting.

In KDE4, it can be found in the Settings menu under `Window Behavior-> Window Behavior-> Advanced` -  the setting is called `Hide utility windows for inactive applications`.   See also [Qt::Tool window diasappears when application become inactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319105/qttool-window-diasappears-when-application-become-inactive)

Comment: It's better to answer like you did, especially since both question and asnwer was well formulated. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @Macke Thanks, hopefully it's useful to someone.   (I did try searchng of course, so even if it's not a common question, maybe this will make the next guy's search shorter.)   And thanks - long-time reader, recently started posting.